# Is there a real Android visual designer for IDEs?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to develop an **Android** application with UI. So it's little complex for me to create UI with codes. I was using **Visual Studio** for long time where visual design is piece of cake. I also used **Netbeans** and **Eclipse** for java applications with UI but when it comes to **Android** I can't find a good way for UI desing. There is a visual design part in **Eclipse** but I want to use **Netbeans** as long as it's possible. Also I think **DroidDraw** is not good enaugh too. So I seached on web for **Netbean's** visual design tool and found nothing. If there is no tool or plug-in like this WHY? Thank you for any help.

Edit:
Well, long time passed. I just get used to code my ui. Also I am using Android Studio. 8)

Answer (score 0):

## edit

just saw that you've used DroidDraw.

There is official GUI designer included in ADT. Browse for main.xml (project/res/layout/main.xml) and doubleclick it :)

enjoy!

Comment: I thought the OP said that they thought DroidDraw wasn't good enough.

Comment: doubleclicking on it works for eclipse but not for my netbeans. Is there a name of ADT you are using?

Comment: @RichardA: answer is updated ;)

PsyCoder: I'm using eclipse only, sry :(

Comment: @RichardA Never said anything good about DroidDraw. Just noticed he said that.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of ADT (Android Development Kit) and eclipse  3.1 + will help you to develop the application graphically. Once you open the layout xml files, click “Graphical Layout” tab at the bottom of the section to open the graphical view. Now you can drag and drop components & also update layout.

*But it is better to understand how the xml is defined in the layout. This will help you to fix any problems (in case).*

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using Embarcadero RAD Studio XE7 (delphi or c++builder) allows for that task but it builds apk files with ome 10mo,